# Use conditional type in function

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I am trying to use conditional type to link two parameters in a function, but I couldn't sort out to link 2 parameters when defining a function. Below is the simplified sample or [the live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-einstein-fcl3e?file=/src/index.ts:0-1026).

```typescript
type Circle = { type: "circle"; data: { radius: number } };

type Rect = { type: "rect"; data: { width: number; height: number } };

type DefinedShape = Circle | Rect;

type FilterShapeByType<Shape, Type> = Shape extends { type: Type }
  ? Shape
  : never;

type DrawShape = <T extends DefinedShape["type"]>(
  type: T,
  data: FilterShapeByType<DefinedShape, T>["data"]
) => void;

let drawShape1: DrawShape = () => {};
drawShape1("rect", { height: 12, width: 22 }); // pass
drawShape1("rect", { height: 12, width: 22, radius: 23 }); // failed, radius is not defined
drawShape1("circle", { radius: 12 }); // pass
drawShape1("circle", { radius: 12, len: 23 }); // failed, len is not defined

const drawShape2: DrawShape = (type, data) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "circle":
      console.log(data.radius); // failed, Property 'radius' does not exist on type '(FilterShapeByType<Circle, T> | FilterShapeByType<Rect, T>)["data"]'.
      break;
    case "rect":
      console.log(data.height, data.width);
      break;
  }
};
```

the original goal is to link the two parameters in `DrawShape` function, meaning when `type` is `circle`, the `data` should be `{radius: number}`. I use the conditional type `FilterShapeByType` to sort it out.

All good before I try to define a function `drawShape2`. I am expecting when I use switch for the `type` for `circle`, the typescript should smart enough to assume `data` should be the `Circle['data']`, however it didn't. Wondering is there easy to make it automatically?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=3#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%200VEQD0vUOXp3XUVtcHGD9nj%20EoEG6Ko2ggOp4HTCBIU6dIYIBcoEPqTJgHQhEYWMR4PwPLcpiEPQ6AAa2ybcdxXYh1QMTdZAYpdWy4fcICPE8z2MA9tQ8IdBIFGxxQoqAqIgWj6ImWRaSAA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

Answer (score 2):

There is one trick. Don't tell anybody :D

Just use named tuples

```js
  function drawShape2(...args: [type: 'circle', data: Circle['data']] | [type: 'rect', data: Rect['data']]) {
    switch (args[0]) {
      case "circle":
        const [type1, data1] = args;
        break;
      case "rect":
        const [type2, data2] = args
        break;
    }
  };
```

Comment: In my case there are many types, I think it will be verbose and duplicated. Anyway, It's a good tricky, learned, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious of why your code isn't working. Looks like it should work, but it doesn't! I might have missed something, or it's a limitation from TypeScript.

Either way, here's a workaround that I prefer (using [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)):

```
type Shapes = {
  circle: { radius: number },
  rect: { width: number; height: number }
}

type ShapeTypes = keyof Shapes;

type DrawShape = <T extends ShapeTypes>(type: T, data: Shapes[T]) => void;

const isShapeOf = <T extends ShapeTypes>(expected: T, type: string, data: any): data is Shapes[T] => {
  return expected === type;
}

const drawShape: DrawShape = (type, data) => {
  if (isShapeOf("circle", type, data)) {
    data.radius; // pass
  } else if (isShapeOf("rect", type, data)) {
    data.radius; // radius does not exist
    data.width; // pass
    data.height; // pass
  }
};

drawShape("rect", { height: 12, width: 22 }); // pass
drawShape("rect", { height: 12, width: 22, radius: 23 }); // failed, radius is not defined
drawShape("circle", { radius: 12 }); // pass
drawShape("circle", { radius: 12, len: 23 }); // failed, len is not defined
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0gZygXigbwLACgpQDGAlgE6EA2EAXFlKQgCbECuytAdiwLYBGEpKAF8ANHgKkIhYLUxQA7sUbA4nHv1IBuKHAjEA5nBlQufAcLxC8eUJFiJIAFXARUGANYQQAewBm9pFdNa1xbaAARBnl4QPQoAB5HKAgAD2AIDkZUGKcXZAA+AAow2kcRKEYEYARaHNcAbUcAXQBKdHyoADdvJWDcPEJvDmRgKGJkOoB5fwxE5LSMrIDclCLUyGkIRlLykqgR0mIOfXLK6toEDhAW2jOEMeyHBub2rHF6CGAWUg55jfTGOg0Bgwn0rP1cINhqNGFE6rRIghok84sUXKcqgg2mgOjh8GN-IVxlNfIUAEQkchUMm7dEVTEtNp4ggEO4AOgYzDY2gA9DyoGAEMhkO8hMkKMhoMRCcSntNyZJpDSoGEMdVGW98azMRymKxkLz+Zz9RVvK4TN5RqlxsB3trqmzFMo4IaBUKRVr6Q7dAYjK7BcLRZY+nhYUi6gqpMBlXIfYZjABGABM5SdKloSaTwha-vdobhT0jSvKsb08doydTSnTUEz5WNbAzAGZs67fAhiFRGPW9WwHhaYRBfEctvnw4WKWRKBAY-Re+woMnW1A+W7A7gw8jAuTKdPZw2F5WoFQOM3l6v252tuUT-2OJaKkOR4wgA)

Comment: Seems we have to put the type guard there, and it does the job. However, there is one flaw with this approach, when they are many types, the `if else, else...` statements become very annoying, and it will not warn me if I add one more type.

Answer (score 1):

**The Why**

That's not how the <s>force</s> TypeScript works.

Let's take a closer look at what the type of `data` is in the `drawShape2` signature:

```js
(parameter) data: (FilterShapeByType<Circle, T> | FilterShapeByType<Rect, T>)["data"]
```

What does it tell us? That the type of `data` depends on what `T` is resolved to. In your case, `T` is constrained to `DefinedShape["type"]`, or, inlined, `"circle" | "rect"` (off-note: unless you want to confuse people, please, change the `type` to something more customary like `kind`).

Until you call the function with either `"circle"` or `"rect"` as `type`, `T` stays unresolved. With that said, let's test what is the actual type of `data` given the union `"circle" | "rect"`:

```js
type testFilter = FilterShapeByType<DefinedShape, "circle"|"rect">["data"];
// type testFilter = {
//     radius: number;
// } | {
//     width: number;
//     height: number;
// }
```

It should become obvious why you can't access either of the properties: because you can only access members without type guards if they are present on all constituents of the union (see [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)). `switch` statement does not matter here as the compiler is unable to narrow the union due to unresolved `T`.

If you call the function, you will see there is no error:

```js
drawShape2("circle", { radius:5 }) //OK, no error
```

---

**The What**

Now, what could be done to solve this?

There are several approaches, most are outlined in other answers, I would only like to mention that if you are in control of the public contract, use the `DefinedShape` directly since information necessary for narrowing is contained in `type` property:

```js
const drawShape3 = (shape: DefinedShape) => {
  switch(shape.type) {
    case "circle": {
      console.log(shape.data.radius); //OK
      break;
    }
    case "rect": {
      console.log(shape.data.height, shape.data.width); //OK
      break
    }
  }
};
```